# toggle (hide/show) in Extjs4

Tags: extjs4, extjs

I am trying to do something like : when user click on the button, the child panel will show/hide

the issue is the 'onbtnClick' function is working just once. when i click on the button the panel shows and then when i click it again nothing happens and no errors tho ! the panel should hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, there isn't really much need to pass a boolean param to the function.

If you purely want a 'toggle' function, based on the panels visibility and you have a reference to the Ext component, you can use the `isVisible()` function:

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-method-isVisible

So your onBtnClick function would look something like this:

```
onbtnClick: function (){
    var childPanel = Ext.getCmp('p');

    if(childPanel.isVisible()) {
        childPanel.hide();
    }
    else {
        childPanel.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onbtnClick: function (){
    var childPanel = Ext.getCmp('p');

    if (!childPanel.isHidden()) {
        childPanel.hide();
    } else {
        childPanel.show();
    }
}
```

Instead isVisible() use method [isHidden](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-method-isHidden)() because method isVisible may return false when the panel is covered by other components or is not rendered yet (even when your panel has not got hidden property (hidden = false)).

Answer (score 1):

`panel.getEl().toggle();`
will serve your purpose.

-YP

Answer (score 0):

you have setVisible, taking a boolean parameter to know what to do.

`childPanel.setVisible( ! childPanel.isVisible() )`

This example will actually toggle the visibility at each execution.